# Call method .NET from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method in .NET (GetDataStationParts), which I declare with 2 parameters, I want to call it from a JavaScript, and I use the `InvokeMethodAsyn` function in this way:

```
const { data } = require("jquery");

function GetParteScrap()
{
    var idestacionjs = document.getElementById('getestacion');
    var idmodelojs = document.getElementById('getmodelo');
    var tablascrap = DotNet.InvokeMethodAsyn("YMMScrapSystem", "GetDataStationParts", idestacionjs, idmodelojs);
    console.log(tablascrap);
}
```

To do it, I base it on an example on the web but I'm not sure where it gets the `DotNet` object to then invoke the method, the intention of my code is that after selecting parameters of 2 , go to the database and execute a SQL-level function, which will return a table, with the function `GetDataStationParts`, I try to give it the functionality to execute my method at the DB level as follows

```cs
[JSInvokable]
public async Task<IEnumerable<GetEstacionParte>>GetDataStationParts(int modelo, int estacion) 
{
    var resul = await _context.Set<GetEstacionParte>().FromSqlInterpolated($"SELECT * FROM dbo.GetEstacionParte({modelo},{estacion})").ToArrayAsync();
    return resul;
}
```

The SQL level function works correctly, but when running the application at the console level in the browser, it throws the following error, where it indicates that the function is not defined

[image]

Where could the error be? Thank you for reading

Comment: Can you post a gist or a more complete example of your blazor page?  Specifically the section where you wrap your class in the DotNetObjectReference so the instance methods are accessible

Answer (score 0):

require() is not a feature that is built into the browser. Javascript environment does not understand how to handle require(), In Node.js by Default this function is available.
I suspect you most probably missing some reference here. You can either download require.js from [here](https://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) & link with your application or use below script tag.

```html
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
```